# Is this visitor implementation correct?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant, static-visitor

I am implementing a visitor in order to use it with the **boost variant library**.
I want to know if is correct to specialize `boost::static_visitor<>` with a const reference type.

Note my question here is the following:

**There are any problem specializing `boost::static_visitor<>` to `boost::static_visitor<const T&>` ?**

```
template<typename T>
struct my_visitor : public boost::static_visitor<const T&> {

    template<typename U> const T& operator()(U& u) const {
        // some code here .....
        return X<U>::get_some_t(); // finally return some T.
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question even reading the question a couple times. Could you provide a more complete example about what you're trying to do?

Comment: @MarkB is very simple, I am implementing a visitor in a more complex scenario that this I showed up in the question, and I am getting some weird errors. So in order to discard some possibilities I want to know if there is any problem specializing the static_visitor template with const T&. I am expecting that some expert give me the answer: No that shouldn't give you any problem. Or maybe: Yes, when you do that, occurs (...). Thanks for the interest in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem as long as you don't return a reference to a local/temporary.

Also, be sure to check the validity of the reference over time (it ends when the variant object is destructed, which is when the variant itself is destructed, ***or*** (!) when it is reinitialized).

#### Background and explanation

A variant *contains* an object of the "current" element type, and you can *reference* into that object perfectly fine. **As long as** the variant is not reinitialized to another element type (in which case the reference is "just" dangling, exactly like it would if the lifetime of the referred-to object had ended).

So if `get_somet_t()` returns a `T&` or `T const&` (or something with a suitable implicit conversion) there is no problem.

In a simpler setting let me demonstrate valid options:

```
variant<int, std::string> v1 = 42;

int& i1 = get<int>(v1); // returns by ref, valid
i1 *= 2;

// now v1 contains the updated integer value 84
```

Likewise, you can even make variants of /just references/:

```
std::string s = "hello";
int answer = 42;

variant<int&, std::string&> v2(s);
get<std::string&>(v2) += " world"; // now s contains "hello world"

variant<int&, std::string&> v3(answer);
get<int&>(v3) *= 2; // now `answer` contains 84
```

See it all **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b4fab043bd03b49)**

---

#### Demonstration

Put *yet another way*, the following is fine:

```
struct A { std::string a_property; };
struct B { std::string b_field;    };

struct select_member : static_visitor<std::string&> {
    std::string& operator()(A& a) const { return a.a_property; }
    std::string& operator()(B& b) const { return b.b_field;    }
};

int main()
{
    variant<A,B> v = A { "some string" };

    apply_visitor(select_member(), v) += " suffix";

    std::cout << get<A>(v).a_property << "\n"; // prints "some string suffix"
}
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f517072b44b41ab)** as well.

Comment: Added a demonstration that closely resembles your original case, though even with non-const references under **Demonstration**

Answer (score 0):

What about this, is this neat?

```
public interface Worker {
  <T> T accept( Visitor<T> visitor);
}

public class Developer implements Worker { 
  @Override
  public <T> T accept( Visitor<T> visitor ) {
    return visitor.workAsDeveloper( this );
  }
}

public class Manager implements Worker {
  @Override
  public <T> T accept( Visitor<T> visitor ) {
    return visitor.manageAsManager( this );
  }
}

public class Boss implements Worker {  
  @Override
  public <T> T accept( Visitor<T> visitor ) {
    return visitor.planLikeBoss( this );
  }
}

public interface Visitor<T> {
  T workAsDeveloper( Developer type );
  T manageAsManager( Manager type );
  T planLikeBoss( Boss type );
}

public class VisitorImpl implements Visitor<String> {
  
  @Override
  public String workAsDeveloper( Developer type ) {
    return "Working hard as a Developer";
  }
  
  @Override
  public String manageAsManager( Manager type ) {
    return "Managing smoothly as a Manager";
  }
  
  @Override
  public String planLikeBoss( Boss type ) {
    return "Planning like a Boss";
  }
}

public class App {
  Visitor<String> visitor;
  
  public App( Visitor<String> visitor ) {
    this.visitor = visitor;
  }
  
  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    // Given
    App app = new App( new VisitorImpl() );
    
    Developer developer = new Developer();
    Manager manager = new Manager();
    Boss boss = new Boss();
    
    // When
    app.run( developer );
    app.run( manager );
    app.run( boss );
  }
  
  void run( Worker worker ) {
    System.out.println( worker.accept( visitor ) );
  }
}
```